# Create Vector Tiles from Local GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tiles, vector-tiles

**Background**

In a leaflet application I am currently using geojson-vt to turn small geoJSON files (45MB) into tiles stored as a javascript variable. This cannot be done with the larger files (900MB) due to memory restrictions. I want to take the large files and turn them into tiles saved on my local machine. This way I can grab the nessessary tiles instead of the whole file.

**Research**

I believe something similar to [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) but for vector data is what I need.

[TileStashe](http://tilestache.org/doc/) may yield a solution, but its primary use does not seem to be for my purposes. If this does turn out to be the solution, example useage would help.

How I plan to load the tiles - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732790/how-to-serve-map-tiles-from-a-database-using-leafletjs

Answer (score 2):

GDAL can create vector tiles with the MVT driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html

For converting GeoJSON data into vector tiles which are saved into MBTiles database file use a command like

```
ogr2ogr -f MVT -dsco FORMAT=MBTILES -dsco MAXZOOM=10 target.mbtiles source.geojson
```

Another option is to use Tippecanoe the https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe. GeoJSON is the only supported format as input but that is just what you have. For other formats you can convert source data first into GeoJSON with ogr2ogr. The Tippecanoe manual has examples about that as well.